# Generating Huffman Tables for Motion JPEG on FPGA

Tags: fpga, huffman-code, mjpeg

Iam working on a FPGA implementation of `MJPEG Encoder` which uses standard `quantisation` and `huffman tables`.

**Question:**

Can we generate Huffman tables on fly ?.

I mean that once a frame is given as input, a block in the `FPGA` should generate corresponding `huffman tables` for the `frame`.

The `block` can though relax for sometime because a few upcoming frames will be similiar ones.

I have already gone through `vitter algorithm` (dynamic huffman coding). But I doubt it would be hardware efficient.

It will be helpful if I get some more ideas from people around or from those who have implemented such things already on FPGA.

Something like this :

```
tables = huffmantables(frame)
// wait for some frames
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is: you don't. Use standard Huffman table instead, they may not be optimal, but they are not that bad either.

Building Huffman table is a task for a processor. Unless an hardware-friendly algorithm for it exist, putting a soft-core microcontroller to build Huffman tables may be the most efficient implementation.

I suggest you do some testing to see if you really need it. How many dB of PSNR are you gaining from using optimal tables? Or how many more compression ratio? I found that standard table were good enough for generic  MJPEG and chose for the smaller core over the complicated optimal one.

Comment: I have been using standard tables and the compression ratio is good. I read some research papers, they suggest we can double the compression ratio by using dynamic tables. I have not used optimal tables yet. 

As per your advise I will first try the `optimised Huffman tables` and then will check the `compression ratio`.

I really dont like hard-coding all the `Huffman ROM's` for `Cr` and `Y`. The standard data do not provide the probabilities it have assigned for each pixel value.

It would be a very great help if you share some resource with probabilities of pixel. I find them no where.

Comment: It depends what you are encoding, and on the quantization tables. If you are encoding dark images, than lower values of Y will have a higher probability. If you have a fixed utilization, just go with a sample video to analyze. Otherwise, I would use a standard tables from JPEG or another video standard like MPEG2. Some professional video format have fixed Huffman table (like DNxHD), and they work good enough. You can do better, but then, newer format with adaptive entropy coding does a better job with less complexity... Just make sure it is really worth t before doing it! Keep it simple!